# How can I find out how this thesis was TeXed?

Tags: fonts, packages

[This](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/1bachCommelin.pdf) is the thesis in question. I have never seen this style, both with the transparent large numbering in the top right of the page, and the style of `\mathbb{}`. So I'm wondering how to find this out.

Comment: The general layout (and the PDF info) point towards [classicthesis](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis).

Comment: Hi. That is my bachelor's thesis (-; It is indeed classicthesis with some things tweaked a little bit. I did not have enough time to do the layout properly, and I am actually not very proud of the layout. But I can nevertheless recommend classicthesis fullheartedly (if that is english).

Comment: Obsolete link :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to add a more general advice, if you have TeX Live, you can use the great `pdfinfo` command line tool which will extract the PDF document information for you:

```
$ pdfinfo 1bachCommelin.pdf
Title:          Tannaka duality for Finite Groups
Subject:
Keywords:       Tannaka duality, finite
Author:         Johan Commelin
Creator:        pdfLaTeX
Producer:       LaTeX with hyperref and ClassicThesis
CreationDate:   07/11/11 15:03:13
ModDate:        07/11/11 15:03:13
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          23
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4)
File size:      255430 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

We can find some useful hints there, including:

```
Producer: LaTeX with hyperref and ClassicThesis
```

There we go! `:)`

Of course, the metadata has to be written into the PDF file, so we sometimes have to guess. `:(`

*Addendum:* Speravir also pointed out that most of the PDF viewers can display the document properties, in which both producer and creator entries are listed as well. `:)`

Comment: Also: With the usual PDF Readers one can read the document properties, where the PDF creator & producer are shown as well.

Comment: @Speravir: Oops, thanks for the reminder! I included your note as well. `:)`

Comment: Give me some of your reputation :-) _Oh, no … I know you need it to get your own credit card number ;-)_

Comment: @Speravir: I wish! It's granted only for trusted users (+20k). It might take some years until I reach it. `:)` Speaking of trusted users, I need to watch out for Gonzalo, he's close to 4 x trusted user = my second credit card! Oh no! `:)`

Comment: Step by step: First in short time 10k …